# rosdep update groovy.yaml file not found on groovy

Tags: ros, rosdep, raspberrypi, ros-groovy, raspbian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all!

I am following the Raspberry Pi (Raspbian) Source install tutorial after installing most packages from the repository on http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Raspbian but I am getting this file not found erros:

> pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo rosdep update
> > reading in sources list data from
> > /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d Hit
> > https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/osx-homebrew.yaml
> > Hit
> > https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/gentoo.yaml
> > Hit
> > https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/base.yaml
> > Hit
> > https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/python.yaml
> > Hit
> > https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/ruby.yaml
> > Hit
> > https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/releases/fuerte.yaml
> > ERROR: unable to process source
> > [https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/releases/groovy.yaml]:
> >         Failed to download target platform data for gbpdistro:
> >         HTTP Error 404: Not Found ERROR: unable to process source
> > [https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/releases/hydro.yaml]:
> >         Failed to download target platform data for gbpdistro:
> >         HTTP Error 404: Not Found updated cache in
> > /root/.ros/rosdep/sources.cache ERROR:
> > Not all sources were able to be
> > updated. [[[ ERROR: unable to process
> > source
> > [https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/releases/groovy.yaml]:
> >         Failed to download target platform data for gbpdistro:
> >         HTTP Error 404: Not Found ERROR: unable to process source
> > [https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/releases/hydro.yaml]:
> >         Failed to download target platform data for gbpdistro:
> >         HTTP Error 404: Not Found ]]] pi@raspberrypi ~ $

Is it expected behavior?

Thanks!

**Edit:**
Full script:

pi@raspberrypi /etc $ sudo easy_install rosdep
Searching for rosdep
Best match: rosdep 0.10.15
rosdep 0.10.15 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Using /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7
Processing dependencies for rosdep
Finished processing dependencies for rosdep
pi@raspberrypi /etc $ sudo rosdep init
Wrote /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list
Recommended: please run

```
    rosdep update
```

pi@raspberrypi /etc $ sudo rosdep update
reading in sources list data from /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d
Hit https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/osx-homebrew.yaml
Hit https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/gentoo.yaml
Hit https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/base.yaml
Hit https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/python.yaml
Hit https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/ruby.yaml
Hit https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/releases/fuerte.yaml
ERROR: unable to process source [https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/releases/groovy.yaml]:
        Failed to download target platform data for gbpdistro:
        HTTP Error 404: Not Found
ERROR: unable to process source [https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/releases/hydro.yaml]:
        Failed to download target platform data for gbpdistro:
        HTTP Error 404: Not Found
updated cache in /root/.ros/rosdep/sources.cache
ERROR: Not all sources were able to be updated.
[[[
ERROR: unable to process source [https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/releases/groovy.yaml]:
        Failed to download target platform data for gbpdistro:
        HTTP Error 404: Not Found
ERROR: unable to process source [https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/releases/hydro.yaml]:
        Failed to download target platform data for gbpdistro:
        HTTP Error 404: Not Found
]]]
pi@raspberrypi /etc $

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66562/rosdep-update-groovy.yaml-file-not-found-on-groovy/) by [Marco Poli](https://answers.ros.org/users/4357/marco-poli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 86 on 2013-07-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The repository linking from http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Raspbian was outdated, as pointed out by po1.

It has been updated to contain version 0.10.20 and this solved the issue.

I would like to thank everyone that contributed for their help! Please keep sharing!

---

Originally posted by [Marco Poli](https://answers.ros.org/users/4357/marco-poli/) with karma: 86 on 2013-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There has been a recent change in the rosdistro system, and tools such as rosdep have been updated. I would recommend the following two things:

1. Make sure rosdep is up to date:

   `sudo apt-get update`

   `sudo apt-get install python-rosdep`
2. Run `sudo rosdep init` to reinitialize your /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d, then `rosdep update` to update your local cache

---

Originally posted by [po1](https://answers.ros.org/users/4425/po1/) with karma: 411 on 2013-07-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Marco Poli](https://answers.ros.org/users/4357/marco-poli/) on 2013-07-04**:
I had just installed rosdep for the first time using "$ sudo easy_install wstool rospkg rosdep". Will try the package version. Just cheked: I am running version 0.10.15, which is the same in the package system. Just reminding: this is a Raspbian, not Ubuntu. Thanks!

**Comment by [po1](https://answers.ros.org/users/4425/po1/) on 2013-07-04**:
Raspbian is debian wheezy, and the packages in the repo described in http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Raspbian are made for debian wheezy (Raspbian). However, the python-* packages might be slightly out of date. As they are only python files, it should be safe to take the official ones.

**Comment by [Marco Poli](https://answers.ros.org/users/4357/marco-poli/) on 2013-07-04**:
po1, I am getting the file not found error with the official rosdep, following the tutorial.

**Comment by [po1](https://answers.ros.org/users/4425/po1/) on 2013-07-04**:
Then it means that the ROSPi repo has not been updated with the latest rosdep. Uninstall any version of rosdep and install it from pip: `sudo pip install -U rosdep`, that should do it

**Comment by [Marco Poli](https://answers.ros.org/users/4357/marco-poli/) on 2013-07-04**:
It is indeed outdated. I will get to installing the lastest one and re-check. Thanks!

**Comment by [po1](https://answers.ros.org/users/4425/po1/) on 2013-07-05**:
The ROSPi repo has just been updated with the latest python-* packages, including python-rosdep, check it out!

**Comment by [Marco Poli](https://answers.ros.org/users/4357/marco-poli/) on 2013-07-05**:
This update solved the issue completely. Thank you for the help!